# How to create Tinyint Field in Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have problem in creating tinyint field in MySQL database using Hibernate.

I used to write the Entity class like this

@Entity

@Table(name="tablename")

public class MyEntity {

```
private int id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

And when I check MySQL, id field always end up with Integer(11) , how do I make it as TinyInt ?

Any answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are a few ways of doing this. The first is to use the columnDefinition attribute on the @Column annotation to read something like this:

```
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
```

This is not portable across databases and does not align well with the variable itself being an int. A byte or short may be needed here

Another way is to use the @Type annotation, probably with org.hibernate.type.ByteType since it seems to represent a TINYINT ([link to javadoc](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/type/ByteType.html)).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, It works

using your way, 
- first i create My own Mysql dialect, extends from org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
and then I add
registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "TINYINT");

and then I add columnDefinition = "TINYINT" in @Column annotation

thank you very much, I appreciated that

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the columnDefinition property in the @Column annotation to define the SQL you want to execute if you create your schema from the annotations in your beans.

Answer (score 0):

change int to byte or Byte, no need additional annotation